# How pass parameter in pug?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pug

I have a simple template with URL param but it doesn't work

```
doctype html
html
  head
    block head
      meta(charset="utf-8")
      meta(name="viewport", content="width=device-width")
      meta(http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible", content="IE=edge")
      meta(name="x-apple-disable-message-reformatting")
      link(rel="stylesheet", href="style.css", data-inline)
  body
    p Приветствую #{name},
    p  #{url} // it is work

    p 
      a(href='/' + #{url}) Google // it not working
```

[image]

I tried different variants

"pug": "^3.0.0"

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Are you trying to send an email with a link? How is the `url` parameter passed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer is:

```
a(href=`${url}`) text any url
```